# 3 deep nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I wonder what is the best way to deal with 3 levels deep and deeper of nested forms on controller

**An Example:**

**Shop Controller**

```
def new
   @user = current_user
   @shop = @user.build_shop
   @type = @shop.build_type
end

def create
   @user = current_user
   @shop = @user.build_shop(params[:shop])
   @type = shop.build_type(params[:type])
   if  @shop.save     
     flash.now[:success] = "blah"
     render :show
  else
    render  :new 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If accepts_nested_attributes_for is getting unwieldy, your build methods are really your only other option without doing a deeper refactor of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read up on ActiveRecord's [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) method. It will eliminate the need for all of your `build_...(...)` methods in most all cases, and works beautifully with nested forms.

Comment: Agree with Deefour here, but the Rails world is replete with warnings about doing nested attributes more than two levels deep.  Would recommend that you do a lot of googling on deeply nested models in Rails before you go too far.

Comment: yeah i agree with you man, but sometimes you have to left out the elegancy that do not work to any solution that works.